# anyone help me what is wrong in my code php

Tags: php, mysql

anyone help me what is wrong in my code php, the price details are showing 3 times i need this 3 data from my database shows in one row on this pricing page. here id my web page look like now:

[image: mywebpage here]

its not showing vertically after read data from mysql DB. im looking for the those data price in horizontal.

here is my table:

```
id name     price   status
 1 Basic    19.00        1
 2 Gold     34.99        1
 3 Platinum 67.00        1
```

```php
<?php 

// Include configuration file 
include_once 'config.php'; 

// Include database connection file 
include_once 'dbConnect.php'; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimal-ui" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <!-- for ios 7 style, multi-resolution icon of 152x152 -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-barstyle" content="black-translucent">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../assets/images/logo.png">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Flatkit">
  <!-- for Chrome on Android, multi-resolution icon of 196x196 -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="../assets/images/logo.png">

  <!-- style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/animate.css/animate.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/glyphicons/glyphicons.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/material-design-icons/material-design-icons.css" type="text/css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <!-- build:css ../assets/styles/app.min.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/app.css" type="text/css" />
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/font.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="app" id="app">
<div class="padding">
    <?php 
        // Fetch products from the database 
        $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = 1"); 
        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){ 
    ?>    
  <div class="p-y-lg clearfix">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2 class="_700 m-b">Start up your Business today</h2>
      <h5 class="m-b-md">We create different services for your product. 30 days guaranteed.</h5>
      <a href class="btn rounded btn-outline b-info text-info p-x-md m-y">Start Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-x-lg">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
            <div class="box m-t-n">
              <div class="box-body text-center r-t primary">
                <h6 class="text-u-c p-v-sm m-0 m-t"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h6>
                <h3 class="m-0 m-l m-v">
                  <!--<sup>$</sup>-->
                  <span class="text-2x"><?php echo '$'.$row['price'].' '.PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?></span>
                   <!-- PayPal payment form for displaying the buy button -->
                <form action="<?php echo PAYPAL_URL; ?>" method="post">
                    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_ID; ?>">

                    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

                    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?>">

                    <!-- Specify URLs -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_RETURN_URL; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL; ?>">
                  <span class="text-xs">/ mo</span>
                </h3>
              </div>
              <ul class="list b-t b-b m-0 no-radius">
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Email preview on air
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Spam testing and blocking
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 100 GB Space
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 200 user accounts
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Free support for two years
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-remove text-danger m-r-xs"></i> Free upgrade for one year
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="text-center p-a-md">
                 <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="box-body text-center dker">
                <h6 class="text-u-c m-0 m-t"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h6>
                <h3 class="m-0 m-l m-v">
                  <sup>$</sup>
                  <span class="text-2x"><?php echo '$'.$row['price'].' '.PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?></span>
                  <span class="text-xs">/ mo</span>
                </h3>
              </div>
              <ul class="list b-t b-b m-0 no-radius">
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Email preview on air
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Spam testing and blocking
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 100 GB Space
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 200 user accounts
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-remove text-danger m-r-xs"></i> Free support for two years
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-remove text-danger m-r-xs"></i> Free upgrade for one year
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="text-center p-a-md">
                <a href class="btn btn-block btn-lg white">Start Trial</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="box-body text-center dker">
                <h6 class="text-u-c m-0 m-t"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h6>
                <h3 class="m-0 m-l m-v">
                  <sup>$</sup>
                  <span class="text-2x"><?php echo '$'.$row['price'].' '.PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?></span>
                  <span class="text-xs">/ mo</span>
                </h3>
              </div>
              <ul class="list b-t b-b m-0 no-radius">
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Email preview on air
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Spam testing and blocking
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 100 GB Space
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 200 user accounts
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Free support for two years
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Free upgrade for one year
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="text-center p-a-md">
                <a href class="btn btn-block btn-lg white">Start Trial</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You are looping the whole HTML element 3 times.

Comment: Please use the title to describe the problem, not say that you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to call one particular div inside the loop. Have a look on the following code to get an idea. Also, change the code according to your requirement and conditions.

```html
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimal-ui" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!-- for ios 7 style, multi-resolution icon of 152x152 -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-barstyle" content="black-translucent">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../assets/images/logo.png">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Flatkit">
<!-- for Chrome on Android, multi-resolution icon of 196x196 -->
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="../assets/images/logo.png">

<!-- style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/animate.css/animate.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/glyphicons/glyphicons.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/material-design-icons/material-design-icons.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- build:css ../assets/styles/app.min.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/app.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- endbuild -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/font.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="app" id="app">
<div class="padding">
<?php 
// Fetch products from the database 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?> 
<div class="p-y-lg clearfix">
<div class="text-center">
<h2 class="_700 m-b">Start up your Business today</h2>
<h5 class="m-b-md">We create different services for your product. 30 days guaranteed.</h5>
<a href class="btn rounded btn-outline b-info text-info p-x-md m-y">Start Now</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="p-x-lg">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
<div class="row no-gutter">

<?php 



while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
if($row['id'] == 1){
?>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
<div class="box m-t-n">
<div class="box-body text-center r-t primary">
<h6 class="text-u-c p-v-sm m-0 m-t"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h6>
<h3 class="m-0 m-l m-v">
<!--<sup>$</sup>-->
<span class="text-2x"><?php echo '$'.$row['price']; ?></span>
<!-- PayPal payment form for displaying the buy button -->

<span class="text-xs">/ mo</span>
</h3>
</div>
<ul class="list b-t b-b m-0 no-radius">
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Email preview on air
</div>
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Spam testing and blocking
</div>
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 100 GB Space
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 200 user accounts
</div>
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Free support for two years
</div>
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-remove text-danger m-r-xs"></i> Free upgrade for one year
</div>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="text-center p-a-md">
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } else{?>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
<div class="box">
<div class="box-body text-center dker">
<h6 class="text-u-c m-0 m-t"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h6>
<h3 class="m-0 m-l m-v">
<sup>$</sup>
<span class="text-2x"><?php echo '$'.$row['price'].' '.PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?></span>
<span class="text-xs">/ mo</span>
</h3>
</div>
<ul class="list b-t b-b m-0 no-radius">
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Email preview on air
</div>
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Spam testing and blocking
</div>
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 100 GB Space
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 200 user accounts
</div>
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-remove text-danger m-r-xs"></i> Free support for two years
</div>
</li>
<li class="list-item">
<div class="list-body">
<i class="fa fa-remove text-danger m-r-xs"></i> Free upgrade for one year
</div>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="text-center p-a-md">
<a href class="btn btn-block btn-lg white">Start Trial</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<?php }}?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping the whole HTML element three times but instead of you need only loop col-sm-4 three times() not row three times that's why its showing vertically three times. 
Just replace this below code with your code.

```
    <?php 

// Include configuration file 
include_once 'config.php'; 

// Include database connection file 
include_once 'dbConnect.php'; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimal-ui" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <!-- for ios 7 style, multi-resolution icon of 152x152 -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-barstyle" content="black-translucent">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../assets/images/logo.png">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Flatkit">
  <!-- for Chrome on Android, multi-resolution icon of 196x196 -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="../assets/images/logo.png">

  <!-- style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/animate.css/animate.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/glyphicons/glyphicons.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/material-design-icons/material-design-icons.css" type="text/css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <!-- build:css ../assets/styles/app.min.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/app.css" type="text/css" />
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/styles/font.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="app" id="app">
<div class="padding">    
  <div class="p-y-lg clearfix">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2 class="_700 m-b">Start up your Business today</h2>
      <h5 class="m-b-md">We create different services for your product. 30 days guaranteed.</h5>
      <a href class="btn rounded btn-outline b-info text-info p-x-md m-y">Start Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="p-x-lg">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
          <?php 
          // Fetch products from the database 
          $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = 1"); 
          while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){ 
          ?>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
            <div class="box m-t-n">
              <div class="box-body text-center r-t primary">
                <h6 class="text-u-c p-v-sm m-0 m-t"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h6>
                <h3 class="m-0 m-l m-v">
                  <!--<sup>$</sup>-->
                  <span class="text-2x"><?php echo '$'.$row['price'].' '.PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?></span>
                   <!-- PayPal payment form for displaying the buy button -->
                <form action="<?php echo PAYPAL_URL; ?>" method="post">
                    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_ID; ?>">

                    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

                    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_CURRENCY; ?>">

                    <!-- Specify URLs -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_RETURN_URL; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL; ?>">
                  <span class="text-xs">/ mo</span>
                </h3>
              </div>
              <ul class="list b-t b-b m-0 no-radius">
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Email preview on air
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Spam testing and blocking
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 100 GB Space
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> 200 user accounts
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success m-r-xs"></i> Free support for two years
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list-item">
                  <div class="list-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-remove text-danger m-r-xs"></i> Free upgrade for one year
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <?php if($row['id'] == 1){ ?>
              <div class="text-center p-a-md">
                 <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif">
              </div>
             <?php }else{ ?>
              <div class="text-center p-a-md">
                <a href class="btn btn-block btn-lg white">Start Trial</a>
              </div>
             <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping the entire body 3 times, What you need to do is loop the price card element three times. As of the moment there are three price cards elements in the loop, remove two and try placing the loop before and after the price card element which I assume is the "box-body" div.